# JavaFX and OpenJDK 8 - class file has wrong version 54, should be 52

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, javafx, dependencies

Two months ago I have developed a small application using JavaFX. It was before I have wiped Windows 10 out, and installed Ubuntu.

Today I had to do a small video showing the apps features, so I have created a project in IntelliJ from GIT, as a Maven project.

First of all, I had errors telling me that JavaFX cannot be found. So I have found out what happened with JavaFX - it is no longer inside the JDK but it is standalone now.

I have installed openjfx:

```
sudo apt-get install openjfx
```

It has downloaded version 11.0.2. I have added the jars to Global Libraries, and added them to my projects modules. The imports in Java files were now solved, but when I am trying to run the app - all I get is:

```
Error:(7, 26) java: cannot access javafx.application.Application
  bad class file: /usr/share/openjfx/lib/javafx.graphics.jar!/javafx/application/Application.class
    class file has wrong version 54.0, should be 52.0
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
```

Should I get an earlier version of Openjfx? Or maybe there is another problem with my approach?

FYI: I have researched a ton of questions related to similar problems, but nothing worked. I even switched to Java 11, but this didn't work either.

Comment: OpenJFX is compiled with Java 10. If you want to use Java 8 and JavaFX look for an JDK with JavaFX like ZuluFX from azul.com.

Comment: If you use Java 11 you have to add javafx as an dependency in maven. And when you run your programm you must put javafx on the module-path.

Comment: What JDK you are running with? 52 is class file version for Java SE 8. If you are running with JDK8, than you should not need separate JFX because JFX is bundled with JDK8.

Comment: @HPCS No, JavaFX was never a part of OpenJDK8. It very much depends on your distribution whether it is included or not.

Comment: You are, right I havent noticed that you are using OpenJDK.

Comment: When you tried using Java 11, are you _sure_ you actually used Java 11?

Comment: @Slaw I have installed a standard Oracle JDK 8, which contains JavaFX and everything is fine now ;)